# Can use react native library in react using react-native-web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have developed a `react-native` app. now i want to create web version of app using `react-native-web`.

I can use built in `react-native` components inside web app but can't use libraries like `react-native-vector-icons`, ... .

Is it possible use `react-native` libraries in this way??

Or any suggestion for create web app using `react-native` codes and libraries??